# Windows API and String concatenation

Tags: c++, string, winapi, visual-c++

I'm relatively new to C++ and the Windows API (coming from a Java background) and I was just playing around with the Windows API calling `MessageBox` and other simple functions until I tried to pass a concatenated string from a custom function to `MessageBox` where I noticed a weird output in the generated window.

This is the suspicious function:

```
const char* addFoo(const char* strInput)
{
    return ("foo-" + std::string(strInput)).c_str();
}
```

It just returns the original input with a `foo-` added in front. (I hope I'm not doing anything incredibly wrong there)

In main I then do two calls to `MessageBox` first without calling the function but instead doing all the calculation on the fly, and afterwards calling the function:

```
const char* a = "bar";
MessageBox(NULL, ("foo-" + std::string(a)).c_str(), "The Foobar Experiment", MB_OK);
MessageBox(NULL, addFoo(a), "The Foobar Experiment", MB_OK);
```

This is the result I get by doing the string concatenation on the fly (case 1):

[image: Calling MessageBox without calling my addFoo function]

The result I get by calling the function `addFoo` (case 2):

[image: Calling MessageBox by passing the addFoo result directly]

Does anyone have any idea why I'm getting these unreadable characters on the generated window by using my addFoo function? Thanks in advance and sorry for the long post.

Comment: UB. Your std::string is no longer in existence (local to the addFoo()) when MessageBox uses the pointer to the char array.

Comment: `coming from a Java background` Which means very simply to not use Java as a guide in writing C++ code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two fundamentally wrong things in your code, one being C++ related, the other being Windows related.

First, you are returning a pointer to a local entity, namely the return value of `c_str()` which is a pointer.  Returning pointers to local variables is undefined behavior.  What you want to do is return a *string*, not a pointer.  In C++, there are string types such as `std::string` and `std::wstring` that implement the correct copy semantics that are required to have objects returned safely without error.

```
#include <string>
std::string addFoo(const char* strInput)
{
    return "foo-" + std::string(strInput);
}
```

---

The second thing wrong with your code is that in the Windows world, you have basically two types of applications with respect to character type.  You have the `MBCS` application, and `Unicode` application.

If you built a Unicode application, your calls to `MessageBox` would not have compiled successfully, since `MessageBox` takes wide character strings, not char based strings.  In this case, the proper string type to use would be `std::wstring`.

You more than likely built an `MBCS` application, which in this day and age are becoming very rare.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and your effort put in this. Have a nice evening

Answer (score 1):

```
const char* addFoo(const char* strInput)
{
    return ("foo-" + std::string(strInput)).c_str();
}
```

This returns a pointer to a local temporary string, and its memory is released when your message box is shown.

Replace it by a `std::string` in your case:

```
std::string addFoo(const char* strInput)
{
    return std::string("foo-") + strInput; // not sure about the syntax here
}
```

Then, `std::string` object manages its memory correctly and will make the string pointer remain alive for long enough for the message box to display it. You'll need to include `<string>` to get this defined.

Then, you can use:

```
std::string temp = addFoo( a );
MessageBox(NULL, temp.c_str(), "The Foobar Experiment", MB_OK);
```

Comment: `CString` doesn't exist in the Windows API world.  If anything, a C++ string type such as `std::string` or `std::wstring`.

Comment: OK, changed it ot `std::string`, I thought `CString` was always there, but you are right, it's probably only part of the MFC.

Comment: Thanks for you detailed answer. Have a nice evening